# How to describe the next quotient between sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> In the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is defined the relation $\mathcal{G}$:
>   $$x \mathcal{G} y \iff sin(x-y)=0$$
>   Describe the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathcal{G}$

The quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathcal{G}$ is definited as$\{\mathcal{G}_x : \forall x \in \mathbb{R}   \}$

Let $a\in \mathcal{G}_x  \implies a \mathcal{G}x \implies sin(a-x)=0$

But, if $sen(a-x)=0 \implies a-x=p \pi; p\in \mathbb{N} $
Then $a\in \mathcal{G}_x  \implies a=p \pi +x$

Its just like $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \implies \mathcal{G}_x=\mathbb{R}$

Thats confuses me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: What is sen(x-y)?

Comment: @PVanchinathan fixed

Comment: Hint: use the fact that sine is a periodic function. ALso note that the set of periods is a set closed for addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This isn't a complete answer, but I can't write comments yet.

You've done most of the work already, you've just made a mistake in the line $\mathcal{G}_x=\mathbb{R}$ for any $x$, which says is that any two real numbers are related by $\mathcal{G}$. Is it true that $1\mathcal{G}0$?

If so, then we would have $1=1-0=n\pi$ for some integer $n$, which can't be true because it would mean

(1) for $n\neq0$, that $\pi=\tfrac{1}{n}$ is a rational number, which is false, and

(2) for $n=0$, that $1=0$, which is also false.

The problem stated wants you to find all of the unique "equivalence classes" of $R/\mathcal{G}$ by using representatives, and to write this set in some hopefully familiar way.

To lead you along: What is the smallest number which is both greater than and related to 0? What about for any real $a$?